# How to plot two legend with distplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, seaborn

I want to plot two labels in my graph, but I didn't succeed to do that. It displays only the last label `"Old_Formula"`.

Here is a simple example

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

values1 = np.array([1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 4, 3, 3])
values2 = np.array([1, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 7, 1, 7, 6])
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True)
sns.distplot(values1, ax=ax1, kde=False, label="New_Formula")
sns.distplot(values2, ax=ax2, kde=False, label="Old_Formula")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I added relevant tags and included `import seaborn as sns` for reproducability

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by calling the legend from the figure object `f`. I have specified colors because otherwise you see the same color in both figures and cannot distinguish.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

values1 = np.array([1, 2, 2, 5, 3, 4, 7, 4, 3, 3])
values2 = np.array([1, 4, 4, 6, 3, 1, 7, 1, 7, 6])
f, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex=True)
sns.distplot(values1, ax=ax1, kde=False, color='green', label="New_Formula")
sns.distplot(values2, ax=ax2, kde=False, color='red', label="Old_Formula")
f.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]